# In a Jenkins pipeline, how can I get the current job's full name?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm able to use this to get a job's full name

```
final String jobName = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(JOB_NAME)
```

But I see this in the console when I print `jobName`

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob@27535488[MyJobFolder/MyJobName]
```

How can I get just `MyJobFolder/MyJobName` with a different pipeline function call? I know I can process that string to get it, but there's got to be a pipeline function already. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOL, I've coded this before and just forgot it. It's

```
final String jobName = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(JOB_NAME).fullName
```